# I can't clone my repository in my own git server

Tags: git

I can't clone my repository

I'll explain the steps what I've done
1) I'm using windows 8
2) Run Git Bash
3) $mkdir git_ball
4) $cd git_ball
5) $git init, returns Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Users/user1/git_ball/.git/
6) $ls > list.txt
7) $git add .
8) $git commit -m 'creation of list.txt'
9) $git config push.default matching
10) $git remote add origin /c/Users/user1/git_ball 
11) $git config http.sslVerify "false"
12) $git push origin, it gives: everithing up-to-date
13) $cd .. 
14) $git clone git://192.168.48.189/~/git_ball git_ball2 , (192.168.48.189 is the IP of my local machine)
it gives:
Cloning into 'git_ball2'...
fatal: unable to connect to 192.168.48.189:
192.168.48.189[0: 192.168.48.189]: errno=No such file or directory

I don't know what is missing, I want to clone git_ball using my IP, can you help me about this case. The idea also is cloning git_ball from another PC into the same LAN network using my IP.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clone if you replace the IP address with 127.0.0.1 instead?

Comment: Testing with 127.0.0.1, it didn't work, it shows the same output of fatal: unable to connect to 127.0.0.1...

Answer (score 1):

You missed to configure a remote repository. Have a look at this link: http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/. It is for Linux, but it seems you are using `git bash` so it should work.

Basically, you have to configure two repository on your local machine: the remote and the local repo. To configure the remote repository:

1. `mkdir remote-repo.git`
2. `cd remote-repo.git`
3. `git init --bare`

At this point, you can repeat your procedure to create a local repository, where at point 10 you set the remote to point at `remote-repo.git`.

Comment: Also, instead of repeating all points up to 10 he can just cd back in to `git_ball` and do a `git remote set-url origin /c/Users/user1/remote-repo.git` and then continue with steps 11 - 13.

Comment: @SerbanConstantin: not sure. I think at point 10 he will have no remote at all (`git remote -v` will print nothing), thus trying to set the url directly will probably fail with `fatal: No such remote 'origin'`. Not so sure anyway, I tend to remember the minor amount of information needed and in this case GitHub is my friend: if you create an empty remote repository there, it gives you exact commands to create and push a local one!

Comment: my comment was assuming that he won't be deleting the already-made repository (`git_ball` in the OP).

Comment: ah that makes sense! I didn't understand, sorry!