# Git - How to Push/Clone using 2 Folders on Local Machine

Tags: git

So I'm just starting to learn about Git and I'm trying to learn the relationship between the server and client. I don't want to start using GitHub quite yet. The eventual goal is to use my NAS as a server. My strategy is to create both 2 folders: "RemoteTest" and "LocalTest" folders on my local machine, which will act as my client and server.

Here's what I did:

1. First created 2 Folders: RemoteTest and LocalTest
2. In LocalTest, executed `git init`
3. In RemoteTest, executed `git init --bare`
4. In LocalTest, created new file `test.txt`
5. Added "test.txt" in LocalTest using `git add test.txt`
6. Committed using `git commit -m "Testing 123"`
7. Added the remote location using `git remote add origin ~/Desktop/RemoteTest`
8. Attempted to push content to RemoteTest using `git push`

Everything is good up until step 8, where I then get 2 errors:

1. Fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
2. List item Error: failed to push some refs to 'c:/Users/Test/Desktop/RemoteTest'

What am I doing wrong? Using latest version of Git and Windows 8.1.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't clone my repository in my own git server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348518/i-cant-clone-my-repository-in-my-own-git-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just do the steps you outlined, your local branch has no upstream branch, so `git push` won't know where to push to.

If that is the problem, simply doing `git push origin master` (or with `--set-upstream` if you want your branch to remember it) should work.

(Disclaimer, I would expect the error message to be

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

instead of your errors.)

If not, check that you actually added the remote correctly, starting with
checking what `git remote -v` says. I don't know Windows, but your second error suggests that the remote is indeed correctly set up.

Comment: Following the steps described (but on Linux) I end up exactly as you suppose (as expected).